# How to set vertical space between lists and text and between list items the same as between paragraphs

Tags: koma-script, setspace

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

Sample text:
\begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
    \item Sample
    \item Another one
\end{itemize}
Ending one.

Paragraph.

Another one.

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

As we can see, spacing between list and text is greater than between paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With package `enumitem` you can remove the vertical space for a single list using `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Sample text:
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item Sample
  \item Another one
\end{itemize}
Ending one.

Paragraph.

Another one.
\end{document}
```

[image]

To remove the vertical space for all `itemize` environments use `\setlist[itemize]{nosep}`. `\setlist{nosep}` removes the vertical space for all lists.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}% or \setlist[itemize]{nosep}
\begin{document}
Sample text:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Sample
  \item Another one
\end{itemize}
Ending one.

Paragraph.

Another one.
\end{document}
```

You could also define a new list and set `nosep` for this list. See the package documentation for more information.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{nosep,label=\textbullet}
\begin{document}
Sample text:
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Sample
  \item Another one
\end{myitemize}
Ending one.

Paragraph.

Another one.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn, I love `enumitem`, ... alas it can't be used in conjunction with `beamer`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book` and `report` classes).

```
% listspaceprob.tex  SE 651085

%\documentclass{scrreport}
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\OnehalfSpacing

\begin{document}

Sample text:
\tightlists  % no extra spaces in/around lists
\begin{itemize}
    \item Sample
    \item Another one
\end{itemize}
Ending one.

Paragraph.

Another one.

\end{document}
[![enter co[![enter image description here][1]][1]de here][1]][1]
```

Comment: It works, but I can't use it because I have to use `koma` class.

Comment: @Intolighter I am sorry.